# How to compare _id value of Models made using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, compare, identity

I have the following two schemas of `User` and `Critique` and I've got the data persisted in MongoDB database:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({            
        critiques: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Critique' }],
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

 var critiqueSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    author: {type: String, default: ''},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comment: { type: String, default: '' },
    stars: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    _user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
var Critique = mongoose.model("Critique", critiqueSchema);
```

`user.critiques[0]._id.equals(critique._id)` is giving me `undefined is not a function`.

How to compare `_id` value of a `User` instance with the `Critique` instance?

Answer (score 2):

The `critiques` field of your `user` object directly contains an array of ObjectIds, so it would just be:

```
user.critiques[0].equals(critique._id)
```

`user.critiques` would only contain full `Critique` objects if you chained a `.populate('critiques')` call in the `find` where you obtained `user`.

Comment: I am populating `critiques` as well when querying for `User` instances with a `.populate('critiques')` call.

Comment: When priniting out the values on console, `user.critiques[0]._id` is `5462f51efff2d0241d23599c` and `critique._id` is `5462f39cfff2d0241d235997`. But when I look at the value of `_id` in MongoDB in the `critiques` collection I see the value `ObjectId("5462f51efff2d0241d23599c")`. So when printed on console, `ObjectId("5462f51efff2d0241d23599c")` is printing as `5462f39cfff2d0241d235997`.